# Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set - Networking per Virtual Machine instance

Tags: networking, azure, ip, virtual-machines

If you were to create a Virtual Machine Scale Set in Azure, with one NIC attached to it, will this same NIC be used for all of the Virtual Machine instances in the Virtual Machine Scale Set, so that they will share the "capacity" of it? Or will the Virtual Machine instances be assigned their own individual instance of a NIC, or in some other way be configured not having to share the "capacity" of one NIC only?

If I create a Virtual Machine Scale Set with the following information:

**VMSS Name**: VMSS-01

**NIC Name**: NIC-01

And then spin up multiple instances inside of it, and then go to the networking pane (inside of the Azure Portal) for each of those instances, I see the following properties:

**Name:** NIC-01 (VMSS-01/*INSTANCE_ID*/NIC-01)

**Resource type:** Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines/networkInterfaces

**Resource ID:** /subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/VMSS-01/virtualMachines/*INSTANCE_ID*/networkInterfaces/NIC-01

**INSTANCE_ID* is the actual instance id of the Virtual Machine instance

From the looks of the **Resource ID**, it is its own instance NIC and not shared over instances? Or are these Virtual Machine instance NIC resources pointing to the actual single NIC of the Virtual Machine Scale Set in some way?

The reason/s (amongst other) why I'm asking is because I'm looking at [Public IPv4 per virtual machine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#public-ipv4-per-virtual-machine) of Virtual Machine Scale Sets, and if the Virtual Machine instances are using the same single NIC, the [256 limit of Public IP addresses per network interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#azure-resource-manager-virtual-networking-limits) would apply, blocking me from deploying more than 256 Virtual Machine instances with a Public IP.

***Are each of the Virtual Machines instances assigned their own individual instance of a NIC, or are they sharing a single NIC, hence limiting you to 256 Virtual Machine Instances with a Public IP inside of each Virtual Machine Scale Set?***

I can see that the limit of **Private** IP addresses per network interface is 256 as well, but a Virtual Machine Scale set supports more than 256 Virtual Machine instances. This makes me think that each Virtual Machine instance has its own individul instance of a NIC, otherwise it couldn't provide networking to all of the Virtual Machine instances, right? Or does it work in some other way?

I'm also asking because of network performance, how would it handle i.e. 500 Virtual Machine instances with high network load?

***Are the individual Virtual Machine instances assigned their own network capacity, or do they share?***

Answer (score 0):

> blocking me from deploying more than 256 Virtual Machine instances with a Public IP.

With Scale Set, you would need to have an [Azure Standard Load Balancer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-virtual-machine-scale-sets) on top, that would redirect traffic to each instance depending on the instance state (healthy or unhealthy).

> Are each of the Virtual Machines instances assigned their own individual instance of a NIC, or are they sharing a single NIC, hence limiting you to 256 Virtual Machine Instances with a Public IP inside of each Virtual Machine Scale Set?

Each instance in a Scale Set will have its own NIC and its own IP Configuration. They do not share an NIC. Scale Sets instances are similar to VMs at the instance level. Other than that, they are managed by the Azure Service Fabric, which allows you to have special features such as scaling up/down manually or automatically using metric measurements. Instances are also automatically placed in Placement Groups.

When scaling up or down, a new VM itself is created with its own properties - own OS Disk, own NIC, own IP Configuration.

> I'm also asking because of network performance, how would it handle i.e. 500 Virtual Machine instances with high network load?

Network performance wouldn't really matter if you're just looking at it from an NIC point of view. We now know that each instance will have its own NIC, so the NIC itself will not be a network bottleneck. Network throughput really depends on the [VM size](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes) you're using.

That said, you should take a look at the [considerations and limitations of having large Scale Sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-placement-groups#checklist-for-using-large-scale-sets).

Comment: Wanted to check if you still have any questions with regards to this? If not could please consider to upvote or mark as answer so the question/answer helps the community.